# Tensorboard data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

[image]I have problem with entering Tensorflow data at TensorBoard. I'll leave my code below. Please help me with it by commands, functions or examples of code. You can also modify my code to get it to work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tfc
graph = tfc.get_default_graph()
with graph.as_default():
    with tf.name_scope('placeholders'):
        x = tfc.placeholder(tf.float32, (3, 1))
        y = tfc.placeholder(tf.float32, (3, ))
    with tf.name_scope('weights'):
        W = tf.Variable(tfc.random_normal((1, 1)))
        b = tf.Variable(tfc.random_normal((1,)))
    with tf.name_scope('prediction'):
        y_pred = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        l = tf.reduce_sum((y-y_pred)**2)
    #Добавить оптимизацию тренировки
    with tf.name_scope('optim'):
        #Задать скорость заучивания .001, как рекомендовано выше.
        train_op = tfc.train.AdamOptimizer(.001).minimize(l)
    with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
        #Запись сводки о переменных(скалярных величинах) в заданный каталог журналов
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', l)

    writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('/tmp/lr-train')



    n_steps = 1000

    with tfc.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tfc.global_variables_initializer())
        #Натренировать модель
        with writer.as_default():
            for i in range(n_steps):
                feed_dict = {x: [[1.], [2.], [3.]], y: [2., 3., 4.]}
                _, loss = sess.run([train_op, l], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                tf.summary.scalar('loss', l, i)
                writer.flush()
```

Comment: Can you clarify with what data you are expecting to see, and how (and where) you are starting TensorBoard versus running your code?

Comment: In `tf.summary.scalar('loss', l, i)` you are placing the 'l' operation, I think it should be the result from session.run `loss` value.